# On 'flex' AppEngine, header "X-Zoo" contains the project ID - should I rely on it?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

'project ID', in some Google cloud pages, is called 'app ID'.

X-Zoo has that as an array representation `X-Zoo=[yourProjectId,somethingElse,Etc]`

I don't know whether I should rely on it or not. I need the project ID in order to be able to use the data service. I could add config - but why should I? The container should know its name/projectID and make it accessible, despite the principles of containment.

There is another header "X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid" but it is known to not be available for 1) flex containers, 2) on custom domains, 3) something to do with `follow_redirects`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the environment variable "GCLOUD_PROJECT" to get the ID, see all [environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/upgrading#environment_variable_changes).